# phablet-flash -b behind http proxy?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I was trying "phablet-flash -b" but I got the following fail messages.

```
Starting new HTTP connection (1): cdimage.ubuntu.com
Retrying (0 attempts remain) after connection broken by 'error(110, 'Connection timed out')': /ubuntu-touch-preview/quantal/mwc-demo/quantal-ubuntu_stamp
Could not download build data from jenkins... bailing
```

I guess the download is blocked by my proxy, however, I have already export http_proxy=xxx and I can download the file via browser with the same proxy.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I just wget'ed the data myself (with proxy correctly set in http_proxy) 


`$ wget -r http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/daily-preinstalled/current`


and then 


`$ phablet-flash -p cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/daily-preinstalled/current/`



It's a lot of extra downloading but until the phablet downloader can respect $http_proxy, it's their problem.